What are `proxy-factories` and `master-copies`? Are these contracts deployed in `safe-smart-account` repo?
I've got my networks added on to safe-singleton-factory and got my contracts added to safe-smart-accounts. These are the addresses of my deployed accounts (same as the addresses on other networks)
reusing "SimulateTxAccessor" at 0x38710E559A67ef07bcF8EeA70B076ac8e756DE08
reusing "SafeProxyFactory" at 0x9bc5E71d9E5cC5E0cd6fd96DA22b9a4b417dBAC6
reusing "TokenCallbackHandler" at 0x45a03a27D4BA1B0CC9784E3961C5f6C16aCBd381
reusing "CompatibilityFallbackHandler" at 0x4c95c836D31d329d80d696cb679f3dEa028Ad4e5
reusing "CreateCall" at 0xB22D635D552eC95142E2Abe3FfB859eA7d7C0316
reusing "MultiSend" at 0x228a04A59BEF23106Bcb2b4158422baAC60646Ce
reusing "MultiSendCallOnly" at 0x50cafDD5E439994509202CfCd569DcA7E1fd9659
reusing "SignMessageLib" at 0xA4C2E2a419517d25aFa13e15d051f8c17b4d11Fe
reusing "Safe" at 0xde0347f507E276620C9fbB6DEa8445E7718Fe636
reusing "SafeL2" at 0xD7Fb6fA6F873fCF49629200530B17ad44b2c834A
reusing "SafeToL2Migration" at 0x7Baec386CAF8e02B0BB4AFc98b4F9381EEeE283C
reusing "SafeMigration" at 0xbC69fdD5d92e6e91c5265741c3F6678b8df90fbF

In the step 4 of docs for running locally
Step 4: Add your MasterCopies and ProxyFactories

By default, tx service will auto setup MasterCopies and Proxy Factories for [a of networks](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-eth-py/blob/main/gnosis/safe/addresses.py). If your network is not supported you have to add the addresses manually in http://localhost:8000/txs/admin/

What are MasterCopies and ProxyFactories? Is it a separate contract, or are MasterCopies the contracts Safe and SafeL2 and ProxyFactories contract SafeProxyFactory respectively

Yes, MasterCopies are Safe and SafeL2 contracts while ProxyFactories are SafeProxyFactory. Thanks for pointing this out, we might clarify this in future versions of the docs! In the meantime you can also take a look at the newly released Safe Infra Installation guide.
Hope it helps; Best, Louis
